# Is there any code to add standard error lines in ROC for maxent using R?

Tags: r, roc, auc, maxent

I am using maxent in R to predict the distribution of a certain specie with two climate change scenarios. I am using a simple code to know the ROC/AUC but i want a code that would plot standard deviation line (standard error) with the ROC in the plot. I am mentioning the codes to have an idea about my work.

`me = maxent( mask1, p=train_p, a=train_a, factors=('Soil.type'))`

`e = evaluate(test_p,test_a, me, mask1)`

`e`

`pred_me = predict(me, mask1, ext=ext, progress='')`

`plot(e,'ROC')`
[image: This is the image that is generated with my code]

[image: whereas i want a plot like this]

Comment: what package is this?

Comment: I think the package is `dismo`. It is a species distribution model.

Comment: Yes I am doing my research on Maxent specie dostribution model and using dismo package